# Why we have done { i < s.length() - k }in the for loop Please explain the logic.Given string s and int k

Tags: java, string, for-loop, logic

This is a solution to the lexicographic smallest and largest string In which we are having input Sting s and int k ; k is the length of the required smallest and largest string. Please go through this link ques and it's statementhackerrank.com/challenges/java-string-compare/problem I don't need any correction or so. What I want is an explanation of ""for loop"" What's the logic behind that i < s.length() - k. It's in 4th line and By how it satisfies the condition of lexicographic strings –

```
String smallest = s.substring(0, k);  // Assume
String largest = s.substring(0, k);
String temp;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - k + 1;i++)<<<==== please Explain logic in this line
{
    temp = s.substring(i, i + k);
    if(smallest.compareTo(temp) > 0) smallest = temp;
    if(largest.compareTo(temp) < 0) largest = temp;
}
return smallest + "\n" + largest;
```

}

Link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-string-compare/problem

Comment: Note : I don't need any correction or so please what I need is the  logic of FOR loop

Comment: This question would be better suited to the hackerrank discussion forum for that question than here.

Comment: That's the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61414009/why-we-have-done-i-s-length-k-in-the-for-loop-please-explain-the-logic-giv) from the same author :)

Comment: Why not here? And sorry but the discussion tab of hackerrank is inactive nowadays for 30 days challenge.

Comment: @AlexRudenko But the problem is U don't have answer till now

Comment: The _i < s.length() - k + 1_ in the loop is not related to `lexicographic strings` - it just helps to keep inside a string when you're getting substrings of length **_k_** and generate all possible substrings correctly.   Lexicographic comparison is implemented later in the following lines with `.compareTo` functions.  You have string "abcd" and you find smallest and biggest substring of 2 chars.  You'll get 3 substrings `ab, bc,  cd` with `ab` being smallest and `cd` being largest

Comment: @AlexRudenko  let's have an example for string "abcd", and we need 2 character,therefore k = 2; What's going is  4-k-1 i.e 4-2+1=3; so for(int i = 0; i<3 ; i++),so by it we get 3 sub strings  and i know logic is right. but i am not understanding is why we substracted k what's the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go from start

Assume we have string "abcd", so we cut the smallest and largest from index 0 to 2 - it's substring "ab"

Then in the loop `i` changes from 0 to 3  (4-2+1 -> 3) -- it could start from 1 by the way because we already processed "ab";

i = 0, in line `tmp = s.substring(i, i+k)` we cut the 1st substring from "abcd" starting from index 0 to 0+2->2 --> "ab";

next iteration: i++ -> i = 1: cut the 2nd substring from index 1 to 1+2 -> 3 -> "bc" -- it is larger than "ab", so we store largest = "bc";

next iteration: i++ -> i = 2; detect 3rd substring from index 2 to 2+2->4 -> "cd" - it is larger than "bc", so we store "cd"

i++ -> 3, getting out of the loop, otherwise we'll try to get a substring from index 3 to index 5 which would cause exception I mentioned 2 days ago.

Does this explanation answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot brother. Sorry but I misinterpreted your answer last time

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - k + 1;i++)
```

In this line, we're ensuring that 'i' will not go over the length of the string, resulting in an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

For example, in the following code snippet, notice that inside the for loop, we are accessing the index i+1, hence the condition in the for loop is written as 'i < s.length()-1' instead of 'i < s.length()' which is usually the case.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++){
    if(s.charAt(i+1) == s.charAt(i){
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

The variable 'i' travels from index 0 to s.length()-1 when for loop is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
```

The variable 'i' will travel from index 0 to s.length()-k when for loop is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length()-k; i++)
```

But since we're using substring function and in that function, the ending index is not included, we're adding 1 in the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length()-k+1; i++)
```

I hope I cleared your doubts. Don't be intimidated by this lengthy explanation and take your time to understand what I tried to convey.

Comment: I am very thankful for your answer, but can u also help me in the concept why we substracted k and our condition is satisfied for having any substrings of k length